# Use hook_menu_alter to change access callbacks

Tags: 7, routes, users

I'm trying to working with hook_menu_alter, I'm tryng to change, for example, access callback to an admin path (admin/config/account/people/fields).

I've create a permission and I've added to a role.
Now I'm trying this:

```
function mymodule_menu_alter(&$items) {
   $items['admin/config/people/account/fields']['access arguments'] = array('my custom permission');  
}
```

But it doesn't work.

Can I edit this "system" modules permissions?

Answer (score 6):

Your code is correct (that's definitely the way to override the access arguments for a path using `hook_menu_alter()`).

If it's not working you just need to clear your caches (and of course make sure that your custom module is installed and enabled).

I just copied your code into a test site, cleared the caches, and no longer receive 403 errors when visiting that page as an anonymous user.

Comment: Uh, I don't understand, on my installation doesn't work

Comment: Do you get an access denied or do you just get a page saying "You have no administration items"?

Comment: I'm a stupid :) The path is admin/config/people/accounts/fields and not admin/config/people/account/fields :D Now it works!

Comment: Ah, my bad I must have copied the URL from the browser bar and not from your question

Answer (score 0):

You should not edit any core modules of Drupal. It will result in broken upgrade path of drupal instance.

It is always suggested not to edit any core module.

The menu path you are trying to alter doesn't exist in Drupal 7. Not sure what you are looking for.

Comment: There's no mention of editing core modules in the question, why have you said that? Also the menu path _does_ exist in Drupal 7, not sure why think it doesn't

Comment: The path exists. I'm using a standard hook

Comment: @clive: I was referring to "Can I edit this "system" modules permissions?" ...
serigod: Which module is implementing hook_menu that you are trying to alter ?

Comment: @serigod May be you need to check the permissions in admin/people/permissions for the role you want to provide access.. Then only permissions will apply on path you are trying to use....

Comment: Solved, the path was wrong.

Comment: @sergiod My comment was right "The menu path you are trying to alter doesn't exist in Drupal 7. Not sure what you are looking for." :-)

Comment: ;) but my phrase "Can I edit this "system" modules permissions?" was right, because I want to change permissions on modules, not modules :)